# How can I only retrieve the date? Java

Tags: java

I read it from the logfile but there is something like

```
2021-04-29 18:16:30.038 [POOL-5-THREAD-1]  BATCH ISSUE POLICY END TO END|START:2021-04-29 18:16:30|END:2021-04-29 18:16:30|RES:10MS
```

I will just take 2021-04-29

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Main{

     public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception{
     demoReadall();
     }

     public static void demoReadall(){
          
          try{
               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("testlog.log");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
               String strLine;
               /* read log line by line */
               while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                 /* parse strLine to obtain what you want */
                 System.out.println (strLine);
               }
               fstream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
     }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: `String date = strLine.split(" ")[0];` should do it.

Comment: `strLine.substring(0,10)`

Comment: That'll work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

Regards

Output:

```
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
2021-04-29
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2021-04-29 18:16:30.038 [POOL-5-THREAD-1]  BATCH ISSUE POLICY END TO END|START:2021-04-29 18:16:30|END:2021-04-29 18:16:30|RES:10MS");


while (matcher.find()) {

    String match = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(match);
}
}
}
```

In your code, it would look as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main{

     public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception{
     demoReadall();
     }

     public static void demoReadall(){
          
          try{
               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("testlog.log");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
               String strLine;
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
               Matcher matcher;
               /* read log line by line */
               while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);

                while (matcher.find()) {
                    String match = matcher.group();
                    System.out.println(match);
                }
                   
                 /* parse strLine to obtain what you want */
                 //System.out.println (strLine);
               }
               fstream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

        at Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: I have typo, just replace "public class MyClass{" with "public class Main{"

Comment: Did you resolve it? Check out your working code here: https://onlinegdb.com/SyenYKl1ud

Comment: 2021-04-30 00:00:00.182 [pool-5-thread-1] CXP-UAT2 INFO c.s.application.batch.PaymentJob - Batch Issue Policy End to End|start:2021-04-29 00:00:00|end:2021-04-29 00:00:00|res:176ms

If we just want the date ahead, will we be able to do it or will it take all the dates?

Comment: Replace "System.out.println(match);" with "break;". You will have only the first date in "match" then. Simply break the while loop.

Comment: I ask one more thing. How do we extract messages?
example
2021-04-30 00:00:00.182 [pool-5-thread-1] CXP-UAT2 INFO c.s.application.batch.PaymentJob - Batch Issue Policy End to End|start:2021-04-29 00:00:00|end:2021-04-29 00:00:00|res:176ms
split
1. 2021-04-30
2. 00:00:00.182
3.start:2021-04-29 00:00:00
4.end:2021-04-29 00:00:00
5.res:176ms
about this. Thank you